# Is there a Configuration Software for Linux Servers on the market?

Tags: linux, configuration, ssh, nginx, php

I'm currently working on a Linux (Web-) Server configuration tool, which will allow you to easily manage all Your server-configurations in an graphical intuitive solution.

My tool is written in c# and is designed for windows.

The system will connect to a remote Linux-based Server over SSH and will then be able to configure the Domains/Subdomains, email accounts, ftp accounts, php/ settings, nginx/apache settings ... (all remote per ssh)

- no aditional software/configuration needed
- the system will be able to read the current config and will allow you to easily manage the configuration

I've made an short video of the product: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8buUyOvZrQ

I came from froxlor(php server configuration), which I don't like at all. Because I'm using the server for myself and don't the master/client concept.

**So my Question is:**

Is there an equivalent Product already on the market?
Because if so, I can stop working on my own product.

**Edit**

Is there a tool wich works without client Installation? (not php or in any way web-based)

Comment: The concept itself is flawed: if you like GUI, you simply rent a Windows server and don't bother (they are cheap and reliable nowadays). If you use Linux, you already know about CPanel, Webmin and other stuff for administering servers.

Comment: In my opinion, Windows server and Linux server are two different worlds.

Answer (score 2):

Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix:
http://www.webmin.com/

Comment: Yea I used to use webmin/virtualmin sometime ago, before i decided to ditch it and use the terminal instead, very good tool for starters, might be too plain and less appealing than cpanel, but trust me it has all the options you need, plus lots of plugins.

Comment: I'll give it a try. But my intention was a tool wich works without client Installation.

Answer (score 0):

I built something similar awhile ago and it was a basic WinForms dashboard that managed Linux boxes by interfacing with them via [SharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/).  This was awhile ago, but judging by their soure forge page it is still maintained.